# Error while saving attachment

Tags: python, attributes, outlook, attachment, writetofile

I am new to Python and getting an error which I am not able to get past.

Writing a code to go through my outlook and extract attachment(excel) if subject matches a given string. Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

print "Inbox name is:", inbox.Name

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst ()
while message:
    if message.Subject.startswith('EOD Report'):
        attachments = message.Attachments
        if attachments.Count>=1:
            attachment = attachments.Item(1)
            filename = 'c:\Users\xx\Python\%s'%attachment
            print filename
            attachment.WriteToFile(filename)
    message = messages.GetNext()
```

It run perfectly well if i get rid of 'attachment.WriteToFile(filename)'. However, that particular statement generates error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\.spyder2\.temp.py", line 31, in <module>
    attachment.WriteToFile(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in    __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Item.WriteToFile
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like WriteToFile is not an available method. Try adding a `print dir(attachment)` to see if there is something similar, or just use `open(filename,'w')` etc. to write out the attachment.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
attachment.WriteToFile(filename)
```

try:

```
attachment.SaveAsFile(filename)
```

I think the [WriteToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527126%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) is for when you're retrieving the attachment from the Exchange server itself.

The [SaveAsFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210277%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is for when you're saving the attachment you've read locally from Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The AttributeError is telling you that the Item object does not have a method (or function) called WriteToFile.